# Working with Trees in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this data definition for a tree:

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Tree Int Tree
```

and I have to make a function, `nSatisfy`, to check how many items of the tree check some predicate.

Here's what I've done:

```
nSatisfy :: (Int->Bool) -> Tree -> Int
nSatisfy _ Leaf = 0
nSatisfy y (Node left x right)
    |y x = 1 + nSatisfy y (Node left x right)
    | otherwise = nSatisfy y (Node left x right)
```

Is this the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your `data` declaration has base constructor `Leaf`, but your function uses `EmptyTree`. Which is correct? Meanwhile, the left-hand side of your `Node` case looks like the right idea, but your recursive calls don't really fit the method of solving bigger problems in terms of smaller problems.

Comment: @pigworker sorry, my bad! can you show me how to do it right ? because i'm kinda of lost right now...

Comment: Your definition does not allow any trees that store an even number of integers.

Comment: Let me try to get you less lost without just telling you the answer. Your edit helps, but there is still a discrepancy between the declaration, which says `Leaf` takes an `Int`, and the pattern `Leaf` with nothing standing for an `Int`. Once you've settled the definition, try thinking about how a concrete example should work. Something like `nSatisfy (> 2) (Node (Node ... 3 ...) 4 (Node ... 1 ...))`. When that matches a pattern, what values do the pattern variables take? In the `Node` case, `left` and `right` stand for subtrees of the input, so it makes sense to use recursion for them.

Comment: @pigworker thank for your help, and i'm sorry but i'm really not understanding your idea...

Comment: I'm suggesting you think in terms of examples. If you compute `nSatisfy (> 2) (Node (Node Leaf 3 Leaf) 4 (Node Leaf 1 Leaf))`, what should the value be? The test `(> 2)` tests for being greater than `2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `nSatisfy` function, you should add the number of nodes satisfying the condition in both subtrees with two recursive calls.  The last two lines should be like this:

```
|x y=1+(nSatisfy y left)+(nSatisfy y right)
|otherwise=(nSatisfy y left)+(nSatisfy y right)
```

This way, it will call itself again on the same node but only on the subtrees.

Also, if a leaf contains an integer, as is implied in the data declaration, you should make it evaluate the condition for a leaf and return 1 if it is true, instead of always returning 0.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the main answer, I'd like to offer a slightly different way how to generalize your problem and solving it using existing libraries.

The operation you're seeking is common to many data structures - to go through all elements and perform some operation on them. Haskell defines [Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t%3aFoldable) [type-class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types), which can be implemented by structures like yours.

First let's import some modules we'll need:

```
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid
```

In order to use `Foldable`, we need to generalize the structure a bit, in particular parametrize its content:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

In many cases this is a good idea as it separates the structure from its content and allows it to be easily reused.

Now let's define its `Foldable` instance. For tree-like structures it's easier to define it using `foldMap`, which maps each element into a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) and then combines all values:

```
instance Foldable Tree where
  foldMap f (Leaf x)       = f x
  foldMap f (Node lt x rt) = foldMap f lt <> f x <> foldMap f rt
```

This immediately gives us the whole library of functions in the [`Data.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t%3aFoldable) module, such as searching for an element, different kinds of folds, etc. While a function counting the number of values satisfying some predicate isn't defined there, we can easily define it for any `Foldable`. The idea is that we'll use the [`Sum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t%3aSum):

```
nSatisfy :: (Foldable f) => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Int
nSatisfy p = getSum . foldMap (\x -> Sum $ if p x then 1 else 0)
```

The idea behind this function is simple: Map each value to `1` if it satisfies the predicate, otherwise to `0`. And then folding with the `Sum` monoid just adds all values up.

Comment: thank for your answer, but i think that is a little out of my league, i mean, i just began learning haskell and i'm not familiarised with that stuff, although i will definitely check the Data.Foldable module!

Comment: @user2876457 I understand, it's a lot of new concepts at once. It'll start making more sense later for sure.